# Show two WKWebView side-by-side (similar to DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle) in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, wkwebview, swiftui-navigationview

In a previous version of my app I implemented the double column style with a sidebar on the left and a main view on the right; now I made some changes to the code and the app is pretty much all based on webviews, so the double column navigation had to be removed...and I was wondering if is possible to implement something similar to that style but all webview-based...
To better explain what I mean, here's a screenshot of the app with the NavigationView implemented, and I wrote in red what I want to achieve:

[image]

There are some way to get this? Thank you!